# Handlebarsjs PHP rendering

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I was wondering if there was something out there that would allow php to render Handlebarsjs templates on the server side.

thanks

Comment: Have you considered writing your server-side app in JavaScript instead of PHP if you want to use JavaScript libraries?

Comment: @DanGrossman I want to use handlebars templates in PHP too but I have an HTML5 web app that's pretty much completely driven client side. I want the template as an email template.

Answer (score 23):

I start a new project to do this task, its here :

https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php

Not so much tested but its usable enough.

Comment: Its fully tested now :)

Comment: This repo is now archived.

Comment: Yes, we are not using it anymore, and we can not maintain it. feel free to fork and maintain it.

Answer (score 10):

[lightncandy](https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy) is a pure PHP library that supports almost all features of handlebars *(Does not require a PECL library)*

Comment: Handlbars.php Does not require any PECL library.

Answer (score 6):

Try [mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) it's not the same but handlebarsjs is based on it so it's very much alike.

Comment: I would suggest this as well since it has great contributions, constantly maintained and as John has mentioned, handlebars is based on this as well.

also uses the double curly brackets for templating... thought peeps should know

Answer (score -4):

This heavily depends on how you are dealing with Handlebars templates. Are you embedding them in the HTML? Are you loading them separately? Are you saving them locally and then compiling? If you are embedding in HTML, you can just put some PHP tags there and you're done.

If you are loading them separately, you'll have to load the template file within PHP (e.g: file_get_contents, fopen/fread), process the information you want, and then save the file again (e.g.: file_put_contents, fopen/fwrite).

PHP can render anything. Just put your PHP open/close tags and do your magic.

Comment: OP is asking about a PHP implementation of the Handlebars templating engine.  PHP most certainly can't just do that if you drop some Handlebars template in.