# PHP implementation of Handlebars.js

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I know that Mustache.js has a PHP implementation which is working pretty fine. However, I want to dive a bit deep into helpers so I decided using Handlebars.

Now, I stumbled upon this project https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php and it seems like it can compile Handlebar templates server side. However, there is very little documentation to be found on the google. Is anybody using this one already and can give some hands-on implementing it?

Comment: Comments in the code mention that it's based on Mustache.php, and it works similarly, so it's probably best to just refer to the documentation for that: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php.

Comment: Duplicate of [#11282417](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282417/handlebarsjs-php-rendering)

Comment: https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy